# How do I check if a column exists in my python code, instead of SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import logging
import json
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import warnings

def read_query():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    with open(r'upsert_config.json','r') as ts:
        config = json.load(ts)

    source_driver = config['source_database_params']['source_driver']
    source_server = config['source_database_params']['source_server']
    source_database = config['source_database_params']['source_database']
    target_driver = config['target_database_params']['target_driver']
    target_server = config ['target_database_params']['target_server']
    target_database = config['target_database_params']['target_database']


    conn = pyodbc.connect(
    f'Driver={source_driver};'
    f'Server={source_server};'
    f'Database={source_database};'
    f'Driver={target_driver};'
    f'Server={target_server};'
    f'Database={target_database};'
    f'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    f'MARS_Connection=Yes'
    )

    try:
        source_database=f'{source_database}.dbo'
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        read_table_query="""        
        SELECT distinct table_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME in ('PRCS_DTE', 'EFF_DTE', 'PRCS_RUN_DTE', 'reportDate', 'DateofData', 'InsertDate')
        ORDER BY table_name asc
            """
        cursor.execute(read_table_query)  

        logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))    


    for tables in cursor.fetchall():
        tab = tables[0]
        select_data_query1 = f'SELECT * FROM {source_database}.{tab} WHERE PRCS_DTE > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));'
        select_data_query2 = f'SELECT * FROM {source_database}.{tab} WHERE EFF_DTE > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));'
        try:
            df=pd.read_sql(select_data_query1, conn, chunksize=10000)
            df2=pd.read_sql(select_data_query2, conn, chunksize=10000)
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            continue       
        
        try:
            engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://@{target_server}/{target_database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={target_driver}')

            for chunk_dataframe in df,df2:
                rowcount = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab}', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10)
                warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
                print("{} Records inserted ".format(rowcount) + f"into {tab}")
                engine.dispose()

        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)


           
read_query()
```

I am trying to select all tables with the columns I identified in my `read_table_query`. After that, I want to select data from those tables with data < 2 days old. Then insert that data from that table into a copy of that table. The code works, except when I try to select data from tables that have columns that don't exist.

So the code works if I am just using 1 column in my `read_table_query` but when I add multiple columns I get the error:

`Invalid column name 'PRCS_DTE'` or

`Invalid column name 'EFF_DTE'` or

`Invalid column name 'PRCS_RUN_DTE'` and so on......

I tried adding another dataframe called `df2` to read `select_data_query2` and I get that error with invalid column names on tables that don't have certain columns, then the code runs fine on other tables that DO have the columns. Can I just do an `if...else...` for my dataframe column or should I just ignore the errors that pull from columns that don't exist in some tables?

Comment: What do you want to do if some column X don't exist? do you want to select * without where? And also, haven't you asked a variation of this question the whole week?

Comment: You're not checking for tables that contain all those columns, You're checking for tables with contain _any_ of those columns. Do a group by schema and table, then add `having count(1) = {however many columns you want to be assured are there}`

Comment: Help vampirism?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem. However, you can extract column names before your query and use `if...else` statement:

Try:

```
for col in cursor.columns(table=table_name):
    print(col.column_name)
```